# Multi-platform In-App-Purchase

Tags: in-app-purchase, cross-platform

How to go about designing a multi-platform app that offers In-App-Purchase?

I'm working with JUCE (Win/OSX/Lin/iOS/Andr).

I know that iOS allows IAP. So I'm guessing OSX also does. I would suspect Windows and Android also provide something similar. I doubt Linux provides anything as it is decentralised by nature.

So maybe I would have to write 4 separate IAP modules, and maintain 4 separate stores. Yuck! I don't want to do that. I recoil from duplication.

***Is there any way to unify IAP across these different platforms?***

The ideal solution would be single store to maintain, and a single C++ API to access it.

But is this even possible?  I think Apple explicitly forbid any kind of store/monetising outside of their system. But http://soom.la/ seems to provide some work around for Unity3D.

Answer (score 0):

The api will be same, but the platform specific functionality has to be separate. This way you have one repository and for a given platform build, pull the required code. Here is an example ["Upload XML data to MySQL or NoSQL"](http://oodupinc.blogspot.com/2016/11/defaulthandler-uploadfilestring-read.html)